# Oauth -Visualization api and spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm trying to use the google visualization query language from apps script, but i always receive that error in response to a `UrlFetch` request.
 `https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+*&key=0AlG2PrcwzsrzdGhRalk1M2hvbEZJV0l5SVdYN3AzcGc`.

Error:

```hml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Google Visualization</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Oops, an error occured.</h3>
<div>Status: error</div>
<div>Reason: User not signed in</div>
<div>Description: &lt;a target="_blank" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/"&gt;Sign in&lt;/a&gt;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My code:

```js
var NAME = 'spreadsheet';
var SCOPE = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds';

function testVisualization() {
     Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+*&key=0AlG2PrcwzsrzdGhRalk1M2hvbEZJV0l5SVdYN3AzcGc", googleOAuth_()).getContentText());
}

/*
Authenticate the user when accessing data from Google Services through UrlFetch
There are three URIs required to authenticate an application and obtain an access token,
one for each step of the OAuth process:
- Obtain a request token
- Authorize the request token
- Upgrade to an access token
*/

function googleOAuth_() {
 var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(NAME);
 oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope='+SCOPE);
 oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken');
 oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken');
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
 oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
 return {oAuthServiceName:NAME, oAuthUseToken:'always'};
}
```

Where i miss something?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue. In our case it works for some time, and then sundenly it looses the authentication.

The only workaround I have found was to create another GoogleApp Script file and run the script again. This will force the script to authenticate.

This is very, very anoying, as we've been having to recriate files al the time to keep our script functional. I hope somebody will have a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the **Share settings** from "Specific people" to "Anyone with the link" worked for me.